# C++ shared_ptr void

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I am facing an issue. I created a c++ code snippet from an automated script. In that, I create an object say x and it's handler as xx. It is around 2000 handlers. Out of that there is a chance that the name of object is x and handler name is mistakenly x, instead off xx. The reverse is not happening. Since the handler is of shared_ptr<void>, it is accepting that without any compiler error. What I am looking for is to ensure a compiler error and avoid a run time error. The code is as follows.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>   

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Foo";
    }

};
typedef shared_ptr<A> A_SharedPtr;
typedef shared_ptr<void> A_Handler;

struct packet
{
    A_SharedPtr mem_1;
    A_Handler   mem_2;
    packet(A_SharedPtr a1, A_Handler a2)
    {
        mem_1 = a1;
        mem_2 = a2;
    }
};


int main() {
    A_SharedPtr x;
    A_Handler xx;

    packet p1(x, x); //POTENTIAL ERROR WHICH LEADS TO RUNTIME EXCEPTION
    packet p2(x, xx);//CORRECT ONE

}
```

Could you suggest, a programmer will get a compile error when try

```
packet p1(x, x);
```

saying second argument is wrong?

Comment: You could always just wrap your `shared_ptr<void>` in a thin `struct` wrapper.

Comment: why not use a more meaningful type for your handler e.g: `std::function<void(A_SharedPtr)>`

Comment: @Franois, Could you give a sample snippet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might `delete` the unwanted overload

```
struct packet
{
    A_SharedPtr mem_1;
    A_Handler   mem_2;
    packet(A_SharedPtr, A_SharedPtr) = delete;
    packet(A_SharedPtr a1, A_Handler a2);
};
```

Comment: @nidhinstacknidhin You control the green tick.